# "MySql ErrorTable 'database.Table' doesn't exist" error when getting data using AJax in a intranet environment

Tags: sql, ajax

I receive "MySql ErrorTable 'database.Table' doesn't exist" error on the page I need to call Ajax

when I get the data in my using PHP in my database

if I use localhost to run my application the Ajax work well, however when I put it on the server it get such error

What is the reason, I already grant all the privilege to access the database

I can login to my application, this prove that I am connected to the database

This is my contact.php ajax

```
function loadData(page){
                    loading_show(); 
                      setInterval(function(){                  
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "listcontact.php",
                        data: "page="+page,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {

                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#con").html(msg);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    }, 2000); 
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
```

Just updated

Comment: Show us some code please?

Comment: Update the question with the related section of `listcontact.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said you are able to login and that proves that database is there and you are able to connect to that, in this case only issue can be a missing table.

for your database try executing query show tables;

and check whether the table you are trying to access is available or not.

Comment: But I am able to find the table, it only happen when I use Ajax...:(

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the reason

in the Database I am use contact for the contact Table

in PHP I use Contact, the C is case sensitive